# Count number of records with specific values

Tags: sql, count, case

I have a table:

Table Teams

```
Id_team         member_1         member_2         member_3
1                Alice            Ben
2                Ben
3                Charles          Alice            Ben
4                Ben              Alice
```

I will need to know in how many different teams Alice is a member (doesn't count if she is the first member, second or third). In my sample, the right answer is 2 (with Ben in Id_team 1 and 4, with Ben and Charles in Id_team = 3). Thank you!

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: Isn't this a contradiction: _"1.) I will need to know in how many different teams Alice is a member 2.) doesn't count if she is the first member, second or third"_ ? Do you want to count where she is a member or where she is not a member?

Comment: DIFFERENT TEAMS! :) So, if she is with Ben, it is a "type" of team. If she is with Ben and Charles, another team, If she is with Charles, another type.... Each one have different specialties!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to count "alices" in each column separately to ensure distinct oer column

What you appear to checking is "

```
SELECT
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN member_1 = 'Alice' THEN member_1 END) +
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN member_2 = 'Alice' THEN member_2 END) +
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN member_3 = 'Alice' THEN member_3 END)
FROM tablename
WHERE 'Alice' IN(member_1, member_2, member_3);
```

Update: fixed COUNT

Comment: This will return 7 for the example in the question (3 + 2 + 2)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you want to same teams with different positions (e.g. Alice&Ben, Ben&Alice) count as one.

To do this, order the members in ascending order for alice in every position, and count the results (this returns 2 to your example):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT
        least( member_2, member_3) AS l,
        greatest(member_2, member_3) AS g
    FROM teams 
    WHERE 
      member_1 = 'Alice' 
UNION
    SELECT
        least( member_1, member_3) AS l,
        greatest(member_1, member_3) AS g
    FROM teams 
    WHERE 
      member_2 = 'Alice' 
UNION
    SELECT
        least( member_1, member_2) AS l,
        greatest(member_1, member_2) AS g
    FROM teams 
    WHERE 
      member_3 = 'Alice' 
) q
;
```

Note that this can only be done to the special case of 3 member teams, because least and greatest can select the two other members - for member coun of 4 and greater, a more complex solution is needed.

Comment: what if there are multiple alices in one team, it would be counted twice

Comment: I have only one ALice :). But in your solution I get Count = 3. It is not right. You see?

Comment: Yes, it looks like working. Of course the query is more difficult, I posted only the part unsolved so I will need a little time to try it on real database. I will be back with the result a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to concatenate the fields (sorted alphabetically) in order to turn them into a list of strings.
Then run a `distinct` on this list (so it will list all *separate* teams)
Then search how many strings contains `Alice`

From this the hardest is the "concat alphabetically", as I couldn't really find any good function to do it, but a `GROUP_CONCAT` with a separate `SELECT`s and `UNION`s to convert the fields into rows should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT team_as_string
     FROM (
       SELECT id tid, GROUP_CONCAT(q ORDER BY q ASC SEPARATOR ',') team_as_string
       FROM (
                 SELECT id, member_1 q FROM teams
           UNION SELECT id, member_2 q FROM teams
           UNION SELECT id, member_3 q FROM teams
           /* add more fields if needed */
       ) c
       GROUP BY tid
     ) b
  ) a  
  WHERE team_as_string LIKE '%Alice%'
```

<s>I haven't checked it for syntax errors, but it should be fine logically.</s> Tested and gives the correct answer (2)

This can be enhanced for more members, if needed.

Of course if the members are in a separate join table, then the whole group_concat part can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

> I will need to know in how many different teams Alice is a member

Try this:

```
SELECT 'Alice', COUNT(id_team)
FROM tablename
WHERE 'Alice' IN(member_1, member_2, member_3);
```

The result:

```
| ALICE | THECOUNT |
--------------------
| Alice |        3 |
```

[Fiddle Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69c62/3)

If `id_team` is not unique, use `COUNT(DISTINCT id_team)`.

Comment: id_team is unique. I will try this, it seems to work. Of course the query is more difficult, I posted only the part unsolved so I will need a little time to try it on real database. I will be back with the result a.s.a.p.